# FCSParser in R Python Jupyter notebook wont work on files in flash drive

Tags: python, r, file, parsing, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use fcs parser on some .fcs files stored in a flash drive (the file size is too big to store on disk). I am getting the files like this:

```
data_path_training = "/Volumes/PHILIPS UFD/Data/Training"
#data_path_training = "/Users/Mady/Downloads/data"
files_training = os.listdir(data_path_training)
data_path_validation = "/Volumes/PHILIPS UFD/Data/Validation"
files_validation = os.listdir(data_path_validation)
filesf = \
    [ os.path.join(data_path_training, f) for f in files_training ] \
    + [ os.path.join(data_path_validation, f) for f in files_validation ]
files = []
for file in filesf: #Remove the ".DS_Store files present"
    if file[-3:] == "fcs":
        files.append(file)
```

When I print the list: `print(files)`, all of the elements end in .fcs. However, when I parse them using fcs parser in R, like this:

```
%%R -i files -o data_fcs
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(flowCore)
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
trans = arcsinhTransform(transformationId='arcsinhTransform',a=0,b=(1/5),c=0)
data_fcs <- foreach(file=files) %dopar% {
    library(flowCore)
    fcs = read.FCS(file)...more code in foreach below
```

I get the error:

```
Error in { : 
  task 2 failed - "This does not seem to be a valid FCS2.0, FCS3.0 or FCS3.1 file"
```

When I copied some of the files (like 4) to the disk and ran the exact same thing but changed the path to those files, the code worked perfectly.

What could be the cause? Thanks!

Note: I'm using a 2017 Macbook Pro with 4 cores Intel i5, Jupyter notebook